# Como esconder o tooltip criado pelo atributo Title?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Há como esconder o *tooltip* criado pelo `Title` ao manter o mouse sobre a `IMG`, através de CSS ou JavaScript?

Comment: O atributo alt não cria balão de informações, e sim a tag Title.

Comment: Java ou JavaScript?

Comment: O Khaos tem razão é o tittle que cria o balão !
Javascript, Jquery ou CSS se possivel @bigown

Comment: OK KhaosDoctor falou que o atributo que criar o balão, é o Tittle, e ele tem razão, testei aqui e resolveu, mas já que fiz a pergunta, acho que é melhor alterar o ALT por Tittle, pra que a pergunta possa ser resolvida @bigown

Comment: Ok, você pode [edit] ela então.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edição:** a pergunta original era sobre o atributo `alt`. Sobre o atributo `title`, a W3C tem [as seguintes considerações](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-title-attribute):

- A informação deve ser algo complementar e útil, tal como o que se espera ver em uma *tooltip*...
- **PORÉM**, não se deve contar com essa informação ser apresentada de forma visual...
- E se um elemento não tiver esse atributo declarado, ele o terá com o mesmo valor do primeiro ancestral que o tiver declarado.

Pense bem antes de usar. Fiquem agora com a resposta original.

---

Em geral não é possível, pois isso é um comportamento específico do navegador. A não ser que você queira fazer um fork no código fonte do seu navegador favorito. Mas por favor, não faça isso. Existe um motivo para o `alt` se comportar dessa forma.

Uma coisa que devemos lembrar quando usamos o atributo `alt` é que ele serve como **alternativa** a uma imagem. Embora muitos sites o utilizem como *complemento* para informação visual, o propósito real dele é:

- Ser lida por motores de busca, já que ler texto ainda é mais fácil para as IA's do que interpretar imagens;
- Servir como alternativa para deficientes visuais que teriam problemas com a imagem propriamente dita. Seu navegador tem um modo de acessibilidade por um motivo! E mesmo com esse modo desligado, pessoas com problemas mais leves de visão podem se beneficiar daquela *tooltip*;
- Prover informação para navegadores que não podem renderizar toda e qualquer imagen. Sim, existem, como algumas versões antigas do Silk da Amazon.

As informações acima foram roubartilhadas e adapatadas por *moi* do [site da W3C](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/altAttribute), que é quem mantém esses padrões.

Answer (score 2):

É só não usar o atributo **title** que existe na tag **img**

exemplo:

http://jsfiddle.net/deFreitas/jdgtx1px/

Answer (score 0):

Simples e fácil:

```
$('img').attr('title','');
```